# Query in Firebase database child

Tags: database, firebase

I'm new to android. Can someone help me to query the below-underlined line in the firebase? The query result should be the underlined String.

[image]

That String is an autogenerated one in the firebase at the Driver signup. So hardcoding that string is not my aim.

Comment: Can you please share some code you have already tried to get the key value?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to `Users/Driver` and loop through children, you will get your key:

```
DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("Driver");


ValueEventListener listener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

      //loop through the children
       for(DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

         //get the key or keys depending on how many keys

          String underLinedKey = ds.getKey();

       }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        //log error
        Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());

    }
};
mDatabase.addValueEventListener(listener);
```